# How to publish a SharePoint site over internet?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have created one share point site on a local server. I want to publish into the internet. We have separate public IP server. Share Point is installed on a local server.

How can I publish into the Public IP?

Answer (score 1):

To make the SharePoint site available over the Internet, you will need to

- Create a DNS record point to the Load balancer IP
- Configure IIS binding
- Configure Alternate Access Mapping

> Check the detailed steps at [CONFIGURING ALTERNATE ACCESS MAPPING INSIDE SHAREPOINT SERVER](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)